# What is the proper way to eat lychees?

Tags: fruit

Not long ago, my parents purchased a tin of lychees. They tasted ok when eaten straight out of the tin, but I was wondering: Is there a proper way to eat them (like rhubarb *needs* to be eaten in a crumble with custard) ?

Comment: Oops, I always enjoyed rhubarb crumble _without_ custard. Silly me! Good nobody caught me making such a grave mistake...

Comment: I enjoy rhubarb without crumble, sometime raw, sometimes cooked.

Comment: Me three for the rhubarb without crumble.

Comment: @leftaroundabout heretic! :D

Comment: Just as you've seen with rhubarb, and pretty much any food, there's no one way. So this is unfortunately in one of our common off topic categories. ("proper way" is just asking for things to make with it, plus inviting opinions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No special way.

You can eat them right from the can; they should be already peeled and without the big seed.

You can add them up to a salsa, or a fruit salad; or even cooked dishes (curries).

Answer (score 0):

In the most lychee famous story I know, it is eaten fresh, carried over distances by courier at great expense:

> Lychee was a favorite fruit for Yang, and the emperor had the fruit, which was only grown in southern China, delivered by the imperial courier's fast horses, whose riders would take shifts day and night in a Pony Express-like manner, to the capital. (Most historians believe the fruits were delivered from modern Guangdong, but some believe they came from modern Sichuan.)

Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yang_Guifei

---

[In more recent news, do not allow malnourished children to eat lychee on an empty stomach.](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/01/31/world/asia/lychee-litchi-india-outbreak.html?_r=0) This has resulted in deaths that have just been explained.

Comment: If you're going to quote anything, quote it correct (emphasis mine): *"...a surprising culprit: the lychee fruit itself, when eaten on an empty stomach by **malnourished** children..."*.